# ParseServer : Authenticate User against another ParseServer

Tags: parse-server

We have two different (ParseServer based) apps, that we wish to keep the databases and cloud code separate for technical and security reasons.

However, we'd like to keep the same username/password authentication across both apps - allowing a kind of Single Sign on....

Would it be possible to make one of the ParseServers the 'Master User Authenticator', then use that server to authenticate the users in the second app (maybe using `Parse.User.become` somehow) ?